# Proving that if $a\mid b$ and $b\mid a$, then $a = \pm b$ for $a,b$ as nonzero integers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-explanation, divisibility

Can someone walk me through how to do a proof of the following?

Let $a$ and $b$ be nonzero integers. Use a direct proof to show that if $a|b$ and $b|a$, then $a= \pm b$.

So I know $a,b \neq 0$ in this case. So if I have for example $a=2$ and $b=4$ then $a|b = \frac{2}{4} = \frac{1}{2}  = 0.5$ and then $b|a = \frac{4}{2}= 2$.

I'm then a bit lost?

Comment: $a\mid b$ is a notation for $a$ divides $b$, and *not* for the fraction $a/b$. With the example you gave $2\mid 4$, however it isn't the case that $4\mid 2$.

Comment: As a brief note: $a \mid b$ is not $a/b$. Instead, $a\mid b$ is either **true** or **false**, and means that $a$ divides $b$.

Comment: How well do you know the definition of what `a divides b` means? Usually this is expressed as a zero remainder and some other integer existing so that $b=k*a$ which may help here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confused as to what the notation "$a | b$" means and are confusing it with the fraction "$\frac a b$".  "a | b" is a *statement*.  It means "a divides evenly into b".  It's not a number.  It doesn't have a value.  It's simply either true or false.  You can not say $2 | 4 = \frac 2 4 = .5$" any more than you can say "my name is fred = 564-11-5298".

$2 | 4$ is true because 2 divides evenly into 4.  $4 | 2$ is false because 4 does not divide evenly into 2.  $9|12$ is false.  And $12|9$ is false.  Can you thing of any two numbers where $a|b$ and $b|a$ are both true.

More technically $"a | b"$ means there exist some integer, $m$ such that $m*a = b$.

So if $a | b$ there is some integer, $m$ such that $m*a = b$.

If $b | a$ there is some integer, $n$ such that $n*b = a$.

If *both* are true then $n*b = n*m*a = a$ so $n*m = 1$ so both $n = 1/m$ is an integer, and $m = 1/n$ is an integer.  If $|m| \ne 1$ then $1/m$ is not an integer.  So $|m| =1$ so $m = \pm 1$.  So $b = m*a = \pm a$.

====

One thing to note: if $a | b$ then $|a| \le |b|$.  (Think about it; if something divides evenly into something it most be smaller than than the other thing.  Actually you have to prove that.) That should give you a hint, that $a|b$ and $b|a$ implies $|a| \le |b|$ and $|b| \le |a|$.

Answer (score 8):

By definition $a\mid b$ means that $b=na$ for some $n\in\Bbb Z$. If also $b\mid a$ then $a=mb$ for some $m\in\Bbb Z$. So $a=mb=mna$ and, as $a$ is non-zero, $mn=1$, so $m,n$ are *units* in $\Bbb Z$. The units in $\Bbb Z$ are precisely $1$ and $-1$.

Comment: This is the best, shortest and also my solution of the problem (+1)

Answer (score 5):

$a|b|a \implies |a| \leq |b| \leq |a| \implies |a|=|b| \implies a= \pm b$